# Is there a way to get Firebase Crashlytics Unity C# line number crash information?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics, crash-reports

I've been using Firebase crashlytics for some time and have been trying to get more information on crashes and exceptions on iOS & Google builds. However, I'm can't seem to get the line numbers to show up in Unity C# scripts. Does Crashlytics offer line number details? or I'll have to include another sdk?

Below is an example of an iOS crash.

```
Non-fatal Exception: InvalidOperationException
0  ???                            0x0 ThrowIfCheckDependenciesRunning (Firebase.FirebaseApp)
1  ???                            0x0 GetInstance (Firebase.FirebaseApp)
2  ???                            0x0 get_DefaultInstance (Firebase.FirebaseApp)
3  ???                            0x0 get_DefaultInstance (Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig)
4  ???                            0x0 FetchRemoteConfig (FirebaseServer)
5  ???                            0x0 ForegroundPostSynced ()
6  ???                            0x0 OnSuccessEmp ()
7  ???                            0x0 OnSuccessEmp ()
8  ???                            0x0 OnSuccess
9  ???                            0x0 OnSuccess
```

Comment: Did you upload all the symbols of the app? Check this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=unity#build-project-upload-symbols-android

Answer (score 0):

Unity iOS builds should upload crashlytics symbols automatically (after Crashlytics version 8.6.1) as part of the Xcode build process. This then allows stacktraces to show c# line numbers.

What versions of the following are you using?

1. Unity Editor
2. Firebase SDKs (they should all be at the same version number)
3. [External Dependency Manager for Unity](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver)

Additionally, as another thing to check, are those stack frames/method calls in your user code, in a plugin or somewhere else? If they are not in your code, less information may be available.

Comment: 1. Unity 2021.3.xf1,  2. Firebase 10.3.0,  3. External-Dependency-Manager 1.2.175

Comment: Another question: Is this crash in your iOS build or your Android build? I assume you are also building for android when you refer to "Google builds".

If so, which scripting backend are you using, Mono or IL2CPP? If the latter, are you [uploading symbols](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=unity#build-project-upload-symbols-android)? 

When you run the build does the log contain anything about warnings or errors in [generating debug symbols](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-symbols.html)? Follow-up Are you generating debugging or public symbols?

Comment: This is an iOS crash and base on the firebase documentation the symbols are uploaded automatically.